# Adding a column to Eloquent Model without Migrate -PHP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, migrate

I have an old project which has been migrated to different servers over years. Hence, I can't run any artisan commands on the project.

I want to add a column "sessiontime" to an existing model User. I added the column in the data base table - ALTER TABLE `users` ADD COLUMN `sessiontime` VARCHAR(1025) NULL AFTER `session`;

In my User Model - User.php I added the following code:

```php
public function setSessiontime($sessiontime)
{
  $this->sessiontime = $sessiontime;
}

public function getSessiontime()
{
  return $this->sessiontime;
}
```

In one of my Controllers I am doing this:

```php
$user = User::select('id')->where('email', 'a.b@c.com')->first();
$user->sessiontime = "RANDOMString";
$user->save();
```

But the column in not getting populated.

Is it possible to add a column to an existing table, without having to run artisan migrate?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have a `$guarded` or `$fillable` array defined on your User model?

Comment: No. Only $hidden array defined in the Model

Comment: Ok, then that means, by default, all attributes are `$guarded`. My answer should solve your issue.

Comment: No, I ran a preliminary test and the sessiontime field is still empty - after the user logs in.

Comment: Should i still retain the get and set functions?

Comment: No, they are not needed, and they are not defined correctly anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This likely due to Laravel's default protection against [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment). For any Eloquent model, you have the option of defining ***either*** (but not both) a `$guarded` or `$fillable` array. The `$guarded` array works as a blacklist of properties that are ***not*** mass-assignable, while the `$fillable` property works as a whitelist of properties that ***are*** mass-assignable.

To solve your issue, you probably just need to add the `sessiontime` property to your `$fillable` array:

```
protected $fillable = [ ..., 'sessiontime'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Currently there is no protect $fillable list . The User model just has protected $table = 'users'; protected $hidden = ['field1','field2'] . However there are many fields/columns in the user table - so I am curious to know how does Laravel treat the new field differently - or, why are the other fields not represented in the Model? How does it work differently if I add a new column?